# Update Top query

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I am working with some data on sql server. A table has 4 identical rows and doesn't have any primary key. I wish to update any one row of those 4 may be a top row.

Is it possible to do this? I tried doing that by manipulating update queries in lot many ways, but nothing works...

Comment: Can you not add primary keys for the rows?

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Please show us your original data and what you want to have it as.

Comment: @benni_mac_b not if the records are purely identical.

Comment: @JNK haha very true, my friend.  I took benni_mac_b's comment as just creating the constraint and not adding a column.

Comment: @JNK and you have a typo, there's no "column" keyword for the `alter table` statement ;) I'll chalk that up to a typo :D

Comment: erg i just did an `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN` my bad :)

Comment: My fault for not clarifying - I was thinking as per @JNK.
Have we spammed this question?

Comment: @JNK I knew it was accidental, you are obviously more than an expert with T-SQL. :)  But I figured I needed some witty response to your initial comment. :D

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

The TOP function can be included in a query to limit the number of entries updated by an UPDATE query. In this case a query could be created by adding a WHERE clause to the query which is inclusive of all the identifying fields for the expected matches and use the TOP function as commented earlier. For example:

```
some_table[
  field1, 
  field2,
  field3
]

UPDATE TOP(1) some_table 
  SET field1 = @value1,  field2 = @value2, field3 = @value3
  WHERE
    field1 = @currentValue1 AND
    field2 = @currentValue2 AND
    field3 = @currentValue3;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care which one you get, you can do one of two (simple) things.

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` to create an unique number per row at compile time, or add a field to the table that will identify each row.  Sample code for both is below.

```
CREATE TABLE #blah (Cola char(1), Colb char(1))

INSERT INTO #blah
VALUES
('a','b'),
('a','b'),
('b','c')

SELECT * FROM #blah

SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Cola)
FROM #blah

ALTER TABLE #blah
ADD IdField INT IDENTITY

SELECT * 
FROM #blah

DROP TABLE #blah
```

For a permanent solution, you should go with the `Identity` field.  If this is a one-time thing then the `Row_Number()` option should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is an undocumented unsupported feature of %%physloc%% in SQL Server 2008 which may be equivalent to RowId. I think we should be able to use that.

References
[Code Project Link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/PhysLocOfARowInSqlServer.aspx)

--Solution (Untested)
Assuming we have a table Table1 with two columns Col1 and Col2

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET COL1 = New_Value1,
    COL2 = NEW_Value2
WHERE %%physloc%% IN
(
    SELECT PhysicalLocation
      FROM (
            SELECT %%physloc%% As PhysicalLocation, 
                   ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By Col1,Col2 Order By Col1,Col2) As RowNumber 
              FROM TABLE1) AS T
     WHERE RowNumber = 1 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have table like this

[image]

And you want to update a first row for each duplicate rows

1. Create new column like this

   ```
   alter table TestTable
   Add RowID bigint identity(-9223372036854775808, 1) not null;
   ```
2. update a first row for each duplicate rows

   ```
     UPDATE TestTable SET Col2 = NULL 
     WHERE RowID IN (
      SELECT * 
      FROM (
         select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition BY Col1 order by Col1) rnum
         from TestTable  
      ) T
     WHERE  T.rnum = 1
   ```